# fltk complains about gcc on windows

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, msys, fltk

I've been trying for almost a to build `fltk` on windows in so many different ways but I always end up with:

> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executable 
>   (msys fltk/configure)

or

> Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
>   (CMake-gui)

I've tried it with `fltk 1.3.0` and `1.3.3` and I've even used three different MinGW distros, `GCC` version: `5.1.0`; `4.9.2` and `3.4.5`. Yet it just won't compile. Here is some of the error log generated by the ./configure file:

> $ ./configure --prefix=C:/libs/fltk-1.3.3
>
> ### -----------
>
> ### Core tests.
>
> ### -----------
>
> configure:1336: checking build system type configure:1354: result:
>   i686-pc-mingw32 configure:1362: checking host system type
>   configure:1376: result: i686-pc-mingw32 configure:1439: checking for
>   gcc configure:1455: found /c/mingw32/bin/gcc configure:1465: result:
>   gcc configure:1709: checking for C compiler version configure:1712:
>   gcc --version &5 gcc.exe (i686-win32-dwarf-rev2, Built by
>   MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2 Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation,
>   Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. 
>   There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> configure:1715: $? = 0 configure:1717: gcc -v &5 Using
>   built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=c:\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/lto-wrapper.exe
>   Target: i686-w64-mingw32 Configured with:
>   ../../../src/gcc-4.9.2/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32
>   --build=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw32 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw492/i686-492-win32-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32 --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=win32 --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-isl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-cloog=/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-pkgversion='i686-win32-dwarf-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project'
>   --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw492/i686-492-win32-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe
>   -I/c/mingw492/i686-492-win32-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe
>   -L/c/mingw492/i686-492-win32-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32/opt/lib -L/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/lib -Wl,--large-address-aware' Thread model: win32 gcc version 4.9.2 (i686-win32-dwarf-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)  configure:1720:
>   $? = 0 configure:1722: gcc -V &5 gcc.exe: error:
>   unrecognized command line option '-V' gcc.exe: fatal error: no input
>   files compilation terminated. configure:1725: $? = 1 configure:1748:
>   checking for C compiler default output configure:1751: gcc
>   conftest.c  >&5
>   c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39):
>   undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status configure:1754: $? = 1 configure: failed program was: |
>
> ## line 1728 "configure" | /* confdefs.h.  */ |  | #define PACKAGE_NAME "" | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "" | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "" | #define
>
> PACKAGE_STRING "" | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "" | /* end confdefs.h. 
>   */ |  | int main () | { |  |   ; |   return 0; | } ***configure:1793: error: C compiler cannot create executables* See `config.log' for more
>   details.**
>
> configure: exit 77

I previously compiled 2 other gui libraries with these same tools (nana and SFML), so there can't be anything wrong with the gcc compilers.

**EDIT**

Something (most probably `cygwin`) keeps breaking my `mingw` `gcc` program and every time its "broken" I get  black vcc1.exe windows. Then I must replace the mingw folder to get it working again, this happens mostly when I open netbeans. I just don't know how to fix this, so I've just been avoiding `cygwin` and `netbeans`.

Comment: I see you have quite few MinGW directories there: C:/MinGW, C:/mingw32, and C:/mingw492. Maybe the configure is confused and can't find the C/C++ compiler?

Comment: I initially had MinGW for general C++ compiling, then I had to use mingw32 to build SFML, then finally I had to use another mingw  distro to compile the nana library (I named it mingw-nana). I definitely do not have a directory called mingw492. If this is the problem though, is there a way to specify the gcc compiler
~~~~~~~EDIT: line 19 says otherwise, as it seems to have already chosen a gcc

Comment: Can you try running CMake again and show us the contents of `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` and `CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log`?

Comment: Also, when the broken `vcc1.exe` happens, does restarting the computer fix the problem?

Comment: No, I dont belive so. It also really makes it hard to build anything. I believe I have a virus because in addition to that in the cygwin64/bin/ directory some of the executable begin to have a hidden v<filename>.exe version. Im actually reinstalling both cygwin and tmd-gcc right now

Comment: **No, it doesnt** @kirbyfan64sos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I was finally able to build it yesterday with this version of TDM-GCC (as per the gui installer):

  - MinGW-w64/TDM64 (32-bit and 64-bit) ==> TDM-GCC
- I used he cmake gui instead of the .configure 
  1. open cmake gui. 
  2. input the source code folder (root of fltk folder, ie: "C:/libs/fltk-1.3.3"). 
   3. input the build folder, ie: "C:/libs/fltk-1.3.3/build/". 
   4. click configure 
   5. ** optionally you can change some options but i didn't 
   6. click Genertae 
   7. in cmd (I used git bash though): cd to the build directory and run make or mingw32-make
- I completely uninstalled cygwin because of its interference with the tool chain builds, i.e mingw and tdm-gcc (Still not sure why this happens).

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to setup a development environment is to use [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/).

- Download and install
- Run MSYS2 Shell
- Install some dev tools anf FLTK: `pacman -S make automake autoconf libtool mingw-w64-i686-gcc mingw-w64-i686-fltk`
- Run Mingw64 Shell and you'll be able to easily compile your source: `g++ -o myproject myproject.cpp -lfltk`